# 404 Static file not found - Django

Tags: python, django, web, django-staticfiles

I have an issue with django. I recently bought an instance of a shared server and I wanted to move my django website from AWS to this server (which use Cpanel). All worked fine with AWS but when I switched to Cpanel all statics files were missing.

this is my settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    ]
```

my project structure:

```
my_project
|-app/
    |-...
    |-views.py
|-db.sqlite3
|-manage.py
|-media/
|-my_project/
    |-...
    |-settings.py
|-static/
    |-main_page/
        |-js/
            |-my-script.js
```

I add static files like this:

```
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'main_page/js/my-script.js' %}"></script>
```

This is the error:

```
GET http://my.domain.com/static/main_page/js/my-script.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

When I go to the URL of the file it understands it like one of my URLs:

[image: 404 error screenshot]

I hope you will help me to solve this issue ;)
thanks.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code. I suppose collectstatic command didn't run properly. I don't have any experience with cPanel but have you tried following the steps e.g. in this [tutorial](https://smartlazycoding.com/django-tutorial/manage-static-files-for-django-website-on-a2hosting-com)?

Comment: Have to ask the obvious question ... have you run `collectstatic` on the new setup?

Comment: @urbanespaceman yes I did and nothing change :/

Comment: @PetrHofman I don't have any experience too with Cpanel that why I'm stuck, it worked perfectly on AWS

Comment: How were you serving static files before? Were you running something like nginx in front of gunicorn?

Comment: This was not your issue but similar and likely an error most of us get at some point: if you are running the development server not a prod server, you have to set `DEBUG=True` in the `settings.py` file in order to serve the static files as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add the static & media files config in the urls.py , like this

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] 
urlpatterns  +=  static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

the django docs : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

Comment: I've tried all the same as mentioned in the doc. But still not working for me.
Could you also look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68056926/django-static-files-are-not-being-found-and-loaded?noredirect=1#comment120287953_68056926

Comment: just a note using `django.conf.urls.stati`, this is required `DEBUG=TRUE` in `settings.py` file and it is for developing environment. in production the DEBUG value should be false, your app might act differently in developing environment. see doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Answer (score 0):

For those who still looking for static file solution, please try Django package [Whitenoise](https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It is easy to install and easy to use if you followed the instructions.

some simplified steps:

1. Collect static - make sure static files existing before install

   ```
    python manage.py collectstatic
   ```
2. Install the Whitenoise - this step depends how you managed the packages, update proper file(e.g. Pipfile or requirements.txt) and install. Below command just a example to install the package.

   ```
    pip install whitenoise
   ```
3. Update the static root in settings.py

   ```
    STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"
   ```
4. Add the following to your `MIDDLEWARE` in settings.py - from Whwitenoise docs, Whitenoise package should place after `django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware`

   ```
    `MIDDLEWARE = [
      'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
      'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', #add it here exactly after security middleware
      ...
    ]
   ```
5. now restart or rebuild the app to check whether it is working for you.

**Please check Whitenoise docs if you running into issue about installing the Whitenoise**([Whitenoise docs](https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django.html#add-compression-and-caching-support))

a message for using `staticfiles_urlpatterns`:
**this only works when `DEBUG=True` in `settings.py` which means you should NOT use it for production environment.** see reference [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.urls.staticfiles_urlpatterns)