# How to serve static files in django 3.1

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm use `django 3.1` when I have the option `DEBUG = True` in my settings.py the static files are serve fine, but when I use `DEBUG = False` the static files are not serve I all ready try with this solution:

> [404 Static file not found - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64304144/404-static-file-not-found-django)

In the answer like in de official docs of django use this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] 
urlpatterns  +=  static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

But still doesn´t works. Someone have any idea why still doesn't works.

Comment: You could look into [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/deployment/)

Comment: `python manage.py runserver --insecure`

Answer (score 0):

You can add this

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
)
```

mkdir static

python manager.py collectstatic --noinput

python manager.py runserver

it works