# static files can't be uplaod on cpanel

Tags: css, django, django-templates, static, cpanel

I get error that my static files can't be full executed in my wep app

[image]
This app works correctily on my pc but not on c panel

I am on sharehost so I can't use nginex
How solve this problem

This is my setting:

```
import os
from pytz import common_timezones
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'r&94@o%)q8s-=gmxw@8a9o5161%90&2jo$0*&a&57*5$rx)@ar'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
     #default
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
    #local components
    'omuser',
    'ommessage',
    'omformflow',
    'omflow',
    'omdashboard',
    'omformmodel',
    'omservice',
    'ommission',
   
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'omuser.OmUser'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home/'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'omflow.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',

            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'omflow.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)

LANGUAGES = [

    ("en", "English"),("zh-hant", "Traditional_Chinese"),("zh-hans", "Simplified_Chinese"),("ja", "Japanese"),("ar","Arabic")
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
#TIME_ZONE = 'Africa/Cairo'
TIME_ZONES = [(tz, tz) for tz in common_timezones]
DATE_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d'
DATETIME_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = False

# USE_TZ = True

SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
# SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 3600

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads')
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = BASE_DIR
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 52428800   


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/


STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# static url Mapping folder
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
    #os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'omuser', 'staticfiles'),
)


# staticfiles_dirs Mapping folder

#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'static')

LOG_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs')
LOG_LEVEL = 'ERROR'
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,  
    'formatters': { 
        'simple': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] - %(levelname)-8s - %(message)s',
            'datefmt': DATETIME_FORMAT,
        },     
    },
    "filters": {   
        "infofilter": {  
          "()": "omflow.syscom.default_logger.LowLevelFilter",
          "level": 20
        },
        "warnfilter": {  
          "()": "omflow.syscom.default_logger.HighLevelFilter",
          "level": 30
        }
    },
    'handlers': {  
        'consoleInfo': { 
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
            "filters": ["infofilter"]
        },
        'consoleError': { 
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout",
            "filters": ["warnfilter"]
        },
        'omlogfile': { 
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(LOG_DIR, 'omflow.log'),
            'encoding':'utf-8',
            'formatter': 'simple',
            'when': 'midnight', 
            'backupCount': 10,
            'delay': True
       },
        'djangolog': { 
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(LOG_DIR, 'djangolog.log'),
            'encoding':'utf-8',
            'formatter': 'simple',
            'when': 'midnight', 
            'backupCount': 10, 
            'delay': True
       },
    },
    'loggers': { 
        'django': { 
            'handlers': ['consoleInfo','consoleError','djangolog'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL, 
            'propagate': False 
        },
        'omflowlog': { 
            'handlers': ['omlogfile'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL, 
            'propagate': False 
        },
    },
      
}

DATABASES = {"default": {"ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3","NAME": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.omflow"),"OPTIONS": {"timeout": 300,}}}
```

This is my template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load omflow_tags %}
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
  <head>
    {% include 'base_import.html' %}
    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. We have chosen the skin-blue for this starter
          page. However, you can choose any other skin. Make sure you
          apply the skin class to the body tag so the changes take effect. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/skins/skin-syscom.css' %}">
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/adminlte.min.js' %}"></script>
  </head>
  <!--
  BODY TAG OPTIONS:
  =================
  Apply one or more of the following classes to get the
  desired effect
  |---------------------------------------------------------|
  | SKINS         | skin-blue                               |
  |               | skin-black                              |
  |               | skin-purple                             |
  |               | skin-yellow                             |
  |               | skin-red                                |
  |               | skin-green                              |
  |---------------------------------------------------------|
  |LAYOUT OPTIONS | fixed                                   |
  |               | layout-boxed                            |
  |               | layout-top-nav                          |
  |               | sidebar-collapse                        |
  |               | sidebar-mini                            |
  |---------------------------------------------------------|
  -->
  <body class="hold-transition skin-syscom sidebar-mini">
    <div class="wrapper">

      <!-- Main Header -->
      <header class="main-header">
        {% include 'base_header.html' %}  
      </header>
      <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
      <aside class="main-sidebar">
        {% include 'base_l_aside.html' %} 
      </aside>

      <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        {% block content %}

        {% endblock %}
      </div>
      <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

      <!-- Main Footer -->
      <footer class="main-footer">
        <!-- To the right -->
        <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
           {% omflow_version %} {% omflow_version_type %} 
        </div>
        <!-- Default to the left -->
        <strong>&copy; 2020 <a href="#">The SYSCOM Group</a>.</strong> {% trans '版權所有.'%}
      </footer>

      <!-- Add the sidebar's background. This div must be placed
      immediately after the control sidebar -->
      <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
    </div>
  <!-- ./wrapper -->
   {% include 'base_component.html' %}

  </body>

</html>
```

And this is suptemplate

```html
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %} 
{% load omflow_tags %}  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>OMFLOW</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static "img/favicon.ico" %}" />
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/fontawesome-free-5.13.0-web/css/all.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/fontawesome-free-5.13.0-web/css/v4-shims.css' %}">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css'%}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css'%}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'components/bootstrap-datetimepicker-master/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css'%}">
  <!-- DataTables -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'components/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css'%} ">
  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/iCheck/minimal/blue.css' %}">
  <!-- Google Font
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/jquery-simple-tree-table.css' %}">
  <!-- Select2 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'components/select2/dist/css/select2.css' %}">
  <!-- Ion Slider -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/Ion-Slider/ion.rangeSlider.min.css' %}">
  <!-- daterange picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/CodeMirror/lib/codemirror.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/CodeMirror/theme/eclipse.css' %}">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/SweetAlert2/dist/sweetalert2.css'%}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/select2-to-tree-master/src/select2totree.css' %}">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/AdminLTE.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/omflow.css'%}?version={%omflow_version%}">


  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}"></script> 
  <!-- jQuery 3 -->
  <script src="{% static 'components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'%}"></script>
  <!-- jQuery UI -->
datetimepicker.min.js'%}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'components/bootstrap-datetimepicker-master/js/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.zh-hant.js'%}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'components/bootstrap-datetimepicker-master/js/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.zh-hans.js'%}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'components/bootstrap-datetimepicker-master/js/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.ja.js'%}"></script>
  <!-- DataTables -->
  <script src="{% static 'components/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'components/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-simple-tree-table.js' %}"></script>
  <!-- Select2 -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find the answer here

[404 Static file not found - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64304144/404-static-file-not-found-django)

so add to your urle following

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from .settings import STATIC_URL,STATIC_ROOT
urlpatterns  +=  static(STATIC_URL, document_root=STATIC_ROOT)
```