# django static files are not being found and loaded

Tags: python, css, django, django-staticfiles, static-files

Using django v2.2.1

I have a given project dir. structure:

[image]

In root project dir. there are some static files in `static` dir.

In `base.html` file,

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- favicon --> 
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}" />    

    <!-- Dropzone js -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'dropzone.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'dropzone.js' %}" defer></script>

    <!-- Custom js & css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
    .
    .
```

This is `settings.py` file:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'sales', 'static'),
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

In `urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls), 
    path('', include('sales.urls', namespace='sales')),   
    path('reports/', include('reports.urls', namespace='reports'))   
] 

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Also urlpatterns for `sales`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_view, name='home'),
    path('sales/', SaleListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('sales/<pk>/', SaleDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

Tried

```
$ python manage.py findstatic style.css
No matching file found for 'style.css'.
```

Also I've been getting this error

[image]

I have restarted the server many times.

Comment: Have you added the static urls to your url patterns? Refer [Serving static files during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat yes. forgot to mention that in the post.. updated it now

Comment: Can you show your patterns for `sales.urls`? I believe one of them might be matching your static urls, etc.

Comment: updated the post again

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following to TEMPLATES in `settings.py` should help in your case:

- For Django3.x

```
TEMPLATES = [
 {
    ...
    'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    ...
}
```

- For Django2.x

```
import os
...
TEMPLATES = [
 {
    ...
    'DIRS': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    ...
}
```